# sortable columns in JSP or servlet via column name

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

how to sort data in tables by simply clicking on the headers in html,jsp or servlet.

just for example,try writing c: in address bar of firefox,d directories are listed with sortable columns,how can that be achieved for webpages?

Answer (score 1):

[DisplayTag](http://www.displaytag.org) has great sorting and pagination capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the work of a client side script.

[Datatables](http://datatables.net/) is a great option to work with tables. It supports jquery UI as well.